# Internal crash on Android Q

Tags: android

I haven't had time to start testing Q yet but I've noticed on crashlytics this error being reported. My app itself doesn't use `android.media.MediaHTTPConnection` so i'm guessing it is probably an ad network that is using it but that is all I get on the stack trace. Anyone have any idea what might be the fix? And yes I know what a NPE is but that issue is deep within the Android code and like I said this isn't even something I'm calling on my code.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.okhttp.okio.Segment.limit' on a null object reference
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:1184)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.read(Buffer.java:1223)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:56)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:395)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:165)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:147)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.close(Http1xStream.java:412)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:397)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close(RealBufferedSource.java:385)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:485)
       at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.teardownConnection(MediaHTTPConnection.java:161)
       at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.access$000(MediaHTTPConnection.java:43)
       at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection$1.run(MediaHTTPConnection.java:149)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should decompile your app and see what APIs 3rd party add-ons are in fact using.

Comment: I've also seeing this in my app using okhttp. No idea what causes it nor how to fix.

Comment: Created bug report at: https://github.com/square/okio/issues/591

Comment: Apparently it is a bug in MediaHTTPConnection introduced in Q, I have created a bug report for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130410728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to b0b there’s a tracking bug on the AOSP issue tracker. Want to make sure this gets Google’s attention? Please star this issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130410728

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I've starred it, hopefully more people will.